# XAML data binding - UI not automatically updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've made a program which stores any number of objects of my type Project. Each Project then contains any number of Files, which is another object I created for this program.

The problem I am having arises in XAML, in 2 areas, but which I imagine have a similar origin.

I have a Window which contains a ListView, populated with the Files in a selected Project. From here I can check a box beside each to turn them on or off, and if I select a file, information about it appears in the status bar of this Window.

If I turn a File off, its text colour is supposed to appear light grey in the ListView, but it does not do this automatically; I have to close the Window and re-open it. The File implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and fires this event if the on/off state changes.

I use this XAML code, where the converter is in my code behind class:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibleStateToFontColourConverter}}"/>
     </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also for the selected File, if the information in the file changes while it is selected (which other classes can cause to happen), I want the status bar to update automatically to reflect this change, but it doesn't; I have to click something else and then re-select the File of interest. I implement and use INotifyPropertyChanged for this too, and so I don't know why it doesn't automatically update. My XAML code for the status item is like this:

```
<StatusBarItem Name="statusItem_FileInfo" Content="{Binding ElementName=loadedFiles_ListView, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource GIS_FileToInfoConverter}}"/>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing that will bring it all together?

Comment: show the ItemsSource of your listbox, show the code for your IsVisible Property and show the checkbox code for turn on/off

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding:

```
Value = "{Binding ... , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Call `OnPropertyChanged` directly after you changed the property with the name of the changed property:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler == null) return;
    handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

If you change `"IsVisible"` call `OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible")`

Comment: I have tried that actually but it didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: My code for property changed uses the same template that you've used here. I have a property called IsVisible, and within it the Set part makes a call to OnPropertyChanged("VisibleState").

Comment: As I've written in my answer, when you bind the property `"IsVisible"` you have to call the property changed event with the name of that property.

Comment: when your Property is "IsVisible" then you have to call  OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible") and NOT OnPropertyChanged("VisibleState")

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use a datatrigger for your listbox item? if i get you right you just want to switch between two states?

so default style should be foreground=black and datatrigger Property=IsVisible Value=false --> then foreground lightgrey